# KafkaListener not detected by KafkaEndpointListenerRegistry

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a class as follow and also another class which autowires the infrastructure KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry. However, what I don't understand is why is there no containers in the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry?
In the docs its stated that

> "The listener containers created for @KafkaListener annotations are not beans in the application context. Instead, they are registered with an infrastructure bean of type KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry... Alternatively, you can get a reference to an individual container by using its id attribute"

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/receiving-messages/kafkalistener-lifecycle.html

```java
public class TestListener {

  @KafkaListener(id = "test", idIsGroup = false, topics = {"com.org.testing"})
  public void subscribe(String message) {

  }

}
```

```java
public class Command {
  @Autowired
  private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;  

  public void test() {
    this.kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getAllContainers(); //This one is empty for some reason
  }

}
```

Comment: There is mention of "id" in the documentation - try autowiring with id that is "test" in your case!

Comment: The `TestListener` must be registered in the application context as a bean. Otherwise that `@KafkaListener` is not processed.